# Master Hosts recommendations inconsistency

Tags: openshift

In OpenShift documentation https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/install/prerequisites.html#host-recommendations we have following text:

Master Hosts

In a highly available OpenShift Enterprise cluster with external etcd, a master host should have 1 CPU core and **1.5 GB** of memory, on top of the defaults in the table above, **for each 1000 pods**. Therefore, the recommended size of master host in an OpenShift Enterprise cluster of **2000 pods** would be 2 CPU cores and **5 GB** of RAM, in addition to the minimum requirements for a master host of 2 CPU cores and 8 GB of RAM.

Why it is recommended 1.5GB for 1000 pods, and 5GB for 2000 pods? It looks like misprint. How to estimate RAM properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for 3.5](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/install_config/install/prerequisites.html#production-level-hardware-requirements) is updated:

> Therefore, the recommended size of a master host in an OpenShift Container Platform cluster of 2000 pods would be the minimum requirements of 2 CPU cores and 16 GB of RAM, plus 2 CPU cores and 3 GB of RAM, totaling 4 CPU cores and 19 GB of RAM.